# Horizontal and Vertical ScrollView in android runtime

Tags: android, xml, runtime

I want to implement horizontal and vertical scroll view in activity. I created one code for that.

[image]

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<HorizontalScrollView 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <TableLayout
              android:id="@+id/amortization"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:background="#ffff00">
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 1 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 2 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 3 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 4 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 5 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 6 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/>
              <TextView
                   android:text="Row Data 7 "
                   android:padding="3dip"/> 
          </TableRow>

     </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

How to create table row run time. because table of record is not fix to any limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
LinearLayout table_date         =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_data);


TableLayout tlt     = new TableLayout(Scheduler.this);
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) 
{
    showTime(i,tlt);
}
table_date.addView(tlt);
            TableLayout tl      = new TableLayout(Scheduler.this);
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) 
            {
                TableRow tr         = new TableRow(Scheduler.this);
                TextView tv         = new TextView(Scheduler.this);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                tv.setTextSize(9);
                tv.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                tv.setTag("personal::::"+i);


                tv.setOnClickListener(click);
                tv.setHeight(50);
                tv.setWidth((int)10);
                tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_bg);
                tr.addView(tv);
                tl.addView(tr, new TableRow.LayoutParams((int)10, 50));

            }
            table_date.addView(tl);
```

**showTime function**

```
private void showTime(int i ,TableLayout tlt)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             TableRow tr        = new TableRow(Scheduler.this);
             TextView tv        = new TextView(Scheduler.this);
             for(int i1=0 ; i1<10 ; i1++)
                     {
                 tv.setText((i-1)+".00 AM");

                 tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                 tv.setTextSize(8);
                 tv.setHeight(50);
                 tv.setWidth(60);
                 tv.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
                 tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                 tr.addView(tv);
                     }
             tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_time_bg);
             tlt.addView(tr);

    }
```

**xml**

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/color" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

above code works fine for me.

Comment: how to use it with vertical and horizontal scroll view.

Comment: and what should me my xml file for this